# How to accessgetmapping json response in spring boot program?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postman

This is my JpaRepository interface  ---

```
@Repository
public interface usernameExists extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
    
    boolean existsByUsername(String userName);
    }
```

This is my getmapping controller  ---

```
    @Autowired
    private usernameExists usernameExists;
    
    @GetMapping("/email")
    public boolean doesUsernameExists(@RequestParam String username) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Inside doesUsernameExists");
        return this.usernameExists.existsByUsername(username);
    }
```

When I hit the get request http://localhost:8083/email?username=sandeep@gmail.com I am getting response as true
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trbuw.png)

But, I want to get that response in my spring boot application memory .How to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by application memory? Also use naming convention otherwise you will end up with thousand errors.

Comment: Thanks for responding and for your time . I want to access json data that we get as a response after http get request  in my spring boot java class .

Comment: `true` is the json response. What else would there be? Unless you create a wrapper to carry the boolean there is nothing more to send.